# App check showing Unverified: outdated client requests for all requests with latest firebase 9.15.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

This is what i got from deployed app on firebase. Description for unverified is saying that i have to update Firebase SDK but i have the latest version.

In index.js:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaV3Provider } from "firebase/app-check";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
  measurementId: "...",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app, {
  provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider("KEY"),
  isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true,
});
```

[image: screenshot]

What is the problem and why my all request get unverified? Because of this i cant turn on enforce mode

Comment: Did you find a fix for that? I updated Firebase SDK and now I'm getting around 12% verified requests. But rest are same as yours.

Comment: @Andurit i gave up since then and removed the app check